# How to set the specific value to the concept template class explicit instantiation?

Tags: c++, stl, c++20, c++-concepts

I have codes as follow:

```
#include <concepts>
//Fibo Begins
    template <std::unsigned_integral num>
    struct Fibo {
        constexpr static std::size_t value = Fibo<num - 1>::value + Fibo<num - 2>::value;
    };

    template <>
    struct Fibo<1> {
        constexpr static std::size_t value = 1;
    };

    template <>
    struct Fibo<2> {
        constexpr static std::size_t value = 1;
    };
//Fibo ends
```

Compiler give out an error that argument 1 and 2 is invaild
What's going on here? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the syntax you are using is for a constrained type template parameter, not a non-type template parameter with constrained type. So the compiler is complaining that it expects a type as template argument, not a value.

For a non-type template argument with constrained type it should be `std::unsigned_integral auto num` instead.

But then `1` and `2` have type `int`. They are not unsigned and your type constraint correctly rejects them.

`1u` and `2u` would for example be unsigned integers and accepted by the template parameter.

For a non-type template parameter with a placeholder type not only the *value* provided, but also the *type*, is significant.

It looks though as if you really want the type to be `std::size_t`, not any unsigned integral. So maybe just use that as type for the non-type template parameter instead of the constraint.